# Does Stellar allow the equivalent of Ethereum's transferFrom / erc20 token allowance?

Tags: assets

I'm currently evaluating Stellar for a new project and one of the requirements would be to have a functionality similar to `allowance/transferFrom` from ERC20 tokens on Ethereum.

Is there a way in Stellar to allow a different account to move a specific asset on my behalf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can add [additional signers](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html) to a Stellar account. When you do so, you provide a [key weight](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#set-options), which determines what operations they are [authorised to sign](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#thresholds). For a given transaction, this is done by comparing the sum of the weights of all provided signers against the relevant threshold value set on your account. If the total weight is equal to or greater than the threshold, then the operation is authorised. There are three thresholds, for each of which you can set a different value.

**Example**: you want a single external signer to be able to move funds on your behalf. The [Payment](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#payment) operation that allows funds to be moved is a medium threshold operation. Using the [Set Options](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#set-options) operation, you might set your medium threshold to `10`. Then, using `set options` again, you add your external signer, with a key weight of `10`.

Now that signer is authorised to move funds (as well as perform any other medium threshold operation). They do so by signing a `Payment` operation, with your account as the transaction [source account](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#source-account). If desired, the `low` and `high` thresholds could also be set for security, to further constrain the operations available to this signer.